# Sublime: How to select by single word in CamelCase variable?

Tags: editor, sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, highlight

#### Disclaimer

I apologize ahead of time if this has already been answered elsewhere, but I had little success in finding one. Please feel free to redirect me to another stackoverflow post!

### Example

```
var CamelCasedVariable;
//  ^Cursor is here (to the left of 'C')
```

**Using Mac OS,** `Shift + Cmd + Right Arrow` starting at the specified location in Sublime highlights *all* of `CamelCasedVariable`.

### The Question

**How do I make a single execution of that command *only* highlight `Camel`? Or perhaps there is another keyboard shortcut or package that does this?**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The internal command that does this is the `move` command with a `by` argument of `subwords` or `subword_ends` (depending on which direction you're moving).

The default key bindings for that are <kbd>Alt+Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt+Right</kbd> on Windows and Linux and <kbd>Ctrl+Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Right</kbd> on MacOS. Additionally MacOS also has the same commands bound to <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Right</kbd>, which is probably because on an least some Macbooks the versions without <kbd>Alt</kbd> move between virtual desktops (this may be configurable in MacOS though).

That will give you the subword navigation that you want; include the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key in them to also extend the selection.

These key bindings will be visible in the left hand pane of the window you get when you select `Preferences > Key Bindings` from the menu; you can search for `subwords` to see the full bindings, should you want to change them by adding them to your own custom bindings.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough and accurate solution! This helped me understand how things worked natively in the OS, while still allowing me to get the behavior I wanted specifically.